# Specialised template *not* asserting despite compile time constant static_assert

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

For a few days I've been using and testing my application without any trouble using the following code:

```
class dataHandler
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T GetData(bool truncate = false) { static_assert(false, "Unhandled output type"); }
    template<T>
    int GetData<int>(bool truncate)
    {
        // Normal stuff that compiles
    }
}
```

This (As I expected at the time) works fine as long as no implicit instantiation of GetData's default is performed. However, today after adding a new failing specialisation for `void*` specifically (I wanted a different error) I discovered it wouldn't compile due to the assertion, even though the `void* spec was never called or mentioned in code.

I started a new C++ test project (with the same C++ version, MSVC version, and VS2022 version) and found this also doesn't compile for the same reason:

```
template<class T>
T Spec()
{
    static_assert(false, "default");
}
template<>
int Spec<int>()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I was unable to replicate the original 'success' in anything I tried within the test project, and the failing `GetData<void*>` assert in the initial project seems to indicate that it's not a project config / difference in toolset issue.

After some searching I discovered that it failing was the *intended* (or otherwise expected) behaviour, as well as a workaround for it.

However I find myself wondering *why* the initial case of `static_assert(false)` didn't also fail to compile. Is this some niche exception, or is this an issue with MSVC's consistency?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of the *failing* code to show us.

Comment: `static_assert(false, ...)` is always wrong - a program is ill-formed. Condition should depend on a template parameter, even in a trivial way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm unable to. I'm asking whether or not there's something I'm missing or if it's likely to be an MSVC issue to report.

Comment: @Evg I'm aware, the topic has been covered on SO before (and is what I was referencing in the second last paragraph). The fact that it *was* compiling while being ill formed is what I'm confused about.

Comment: What should "template<T>  int GetData<int>(bool truncate)" mean? Where is T used?

Comment: @Klaus The actual usage of T within the functions is irrelevant to the question, therefore I did not include it. To sate your curiosity it effectively just handles conversion of a void* to certain defined types.

The issue is present regardless of the content of the functions (So long as the static_assert is present, of course).

Comment: I guess that here the standard says that the program is "ill-formed, no diagnostic required". So it's up to a compiler whether to diagnose a problem or not. Authors of MSVC compiler might answer such a question, but they are rare guests here.

Comment: @Evg Aye, my inital assumption was MSVC being inconsistent and strange but my knowledge of C++ is still less than that of people here, thus the question. If it's definitively ill formed by standards that's pretty much the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: When the standard doesn't prescribe a defined behaviour, compilers might be inconsistent, that's something to be expected. Consistent behaviour might be too hard or impossible to achieve in practice.

Comment: "The actual usage of T within the functions is irrelevant to the question, " it is relevant as you write a specialization where you don't get T at all. The code is simply ill-formed!

Comment: @Klaus But it could be provided explicitly. I guess `template<T>` was meant to be `template<>`.

Comment: OP answers in comment, that T is used in the function. And I have no idea how that should work, as the template is declared with one template parameter, that one is specialized with int. If it is used, I have no idea how we can assign a type here. BTW, it should be at minimum <typename T> :-) What so ever, the given code is not valid and gcc and clang reject it. For me it makes not much sense to discuss the behavior of an ill formed program, only because a single compiler is accepting it ( by accident? )

Comment: As far as I can tell MSVC accepts using `static_assert` this way when not in conformance mode (i.e. language standard <= C++17 and no `/permissive-` flag or >= C++20 with `/permissive+` flag). But as mentioned above, it is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. It is up to the compiler whether to diagnose it.

Comment: @Klaus I misunderstood what you were referring to in that case. By "using T in the function" I mean the specialisation of T, not the literal 'T' type. The template<T> was indeed a typo in my post as Evg suggested.

The question is on the topic of whether this is actually an ill formed program being accepted by MSVC or some specific exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I find myself wondering why the initial case of static_assert(false) didn't also fail to compile. Is this some niche exception, or is this an issue with MSVC's consistency?

It's certainly not an inconsistency. The key part here is "Standard conformance mode", controllable with the compiler option `/permissive-`. [See the documentation of this compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170).

The reason that MSVC from before VS2017 used to accept your `static_assert(false, ...)`, is because it postponed parsing the contents of a function template until template instantiation. That is just how the parser used to work, and also why features like two-phase name lookup could never be properly implemented. I'll refer you to [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) for more background on this.

You can easily try it for yourself. Even if the function contains ill-formed code that shouldn't even parse correctly, the compiler doesn't complain as long as the template isn't being instantiated:

```
template<class T>
void foo()
{
    Normally this should not (never actually (compile)) but it does anyway
}
```

It appears to do some basic paranthesis matching and that is it. The token stream is recorded and parsed when `foo` is instantiated (usually when called).

In order to fix two-phase lookup (and other conformance issues), they had to fix the compiler and parse the code whenever a function template is *encountered*, rather than being *instantiated*. But now they have a problem, because a lot of old code might be reliant on the old compiler behavior that suddenly doesn't compile anymore. So they introduced the `/permissive-` option for users to opt-in into standard conformance mode. And gradually the default was changed for new projects or certain compiler options, as can be read in the documentation:

> The /permissive- option is implicitly set by the /std:c++latest option starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, and in version 16.11 by the /std:c++20 option. /permissive- is required for C++20 Modules support. Perhaps your code doesn't need modules support but requires other features enabled under /std:c++20 or /std:c++latest. You can explicitly enable Microsoft extension support by using the /permissive option without the trailing dash. The /permissive option must come after any option that sets /permissive- implicitly.
>
> By default, the /permissive- option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and later versions. It's not set by default in earlier versions. When the option is set, the compiler generates diagnostic errors or warnings when non-standard language constructs are detected in your code. These constructs include some common bugs in pre-C++11 code.

Which brings us to the answer to your question. You weren't seeing it in your original code because you were compiling without `/permissive-`. In your test project, created in VS2022, `/permissive-` mode was set by default so it failed to compile. It also fails to compile in an explicit specialization (your `void*` case) because at that point the template arguments are known and the function is instantiated.

There are a couple of ways to properly fix your code. One is by explicitely deleting the main template and any specialiation you don't want to have.

```
template<class T> void foo() = delete;
template<> void foo<void*>() = delete;
template<> void foo<int>()
{
    // ...
}
```

This will make any use of the explicitely deleted variants ill-formed, without having the option to include an error message. Of course the `void*` case is a bit redundant in this example.

If you want to stick to `static_assert`, you must make the condition for the assert dependent on the template arguments. If you are compiling with C++17, you could do:

```
template<class...> constexpr bool always_false = false;
template<class T> void foo()
{
    static_assert(always_false<T>, "your error here");
}
```

If using C++14 or earlier, you could wrap the `always_false` into a struct template:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class...> struct always_false : false_type { };

template<class T> void foo()
{
    static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "your error here");
}
```

Comment: I just gave it a test and this indeed seems to be correct! Thanks for the detailed write-up. Interestingly, this default seems to have existed on VS2019 but been removed in VS2022 as this project was created with 2019 and partially overwritten (but not deleted and remade) by premake (Though I couldn't find anything mentioning those versions, only 2017).

No doubt this would've caused severe pain and confusion later on had you not explained!